# Is there a single word for "person being questioned"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who questions is a 'questioner' or 'interrogator'.  Is there a word for the questioned, or interrogated, person?

Comment: There's no generic word - it depends on the situation. The person being questioned might be a witness or a respondent, for example.

Comment: _Suspect_, _witness_, and _informant_ could work depending on the context. Can you provide an example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It's not derived from 'question' or 'interrogate', but *subject* might be appropriate:

> 3 c: an individual whose reactions or responses are studied

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject))

It's used multiple times in the [Wikipedia article about interrogation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogation), e.g.

> Interrogation may involve a diverse array of techniques, ranging from developing a rapport with the subject to outright torture.